# Consistent wording for 'improve this question' button when not logged in

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous

When you're not logged in, there is no 'edit' button underneath a question; it shows 'improve this question' instead:

[image]

However, once the suggested edit is submitted, the link changes to 'edit':

[image]

Is this intended or an oversight?

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional.

Once an anonymous suggested edit is submitted, if the edit link is followed from the same location, it will be editing the previous edit suggestion, not making another one. (Remember, those who suggest edits are allowed to edit their edit proposals while they are pending.)

In my opinion, the word "edit" is the right word to use for that case.